# Select matching records from Table 1 if Table 2 has records, otherwise select all from Table 1

Tags: sql-server

**Situation:**

- I have two tables
- Table 1 always has records
- Table 2 is the result of a select statement and may or may not have records

**Desired Results:**

If Table 2 has ANY records, I want only matching records from Table 1.  Otherwise, I want all records from Table 1.

I realize I can do this:

```
DECLARE @count int
SELECT @count=COUNT(*) FROM Table2

IF @count>0
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
ELSE
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

However, I am trying to avoid `IF` statements if possible.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid IF statements?

Comment: I am trying to leverage SQL to its fullest and reduce code I have to maintain.  With the IF, I may have to adjust both select statements in the future.  For me, IF is the safety net if I can't find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  t1.*
from    Table1 t1
left join
        Table2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
where   t2.id is not null -- Match found
        or not exists -- Or Table2 is empty
        (
        select  *
        from    Table2
        )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it had to be possible